# Convert String to U_Char - Using STRTOL() Incorrectly?

Tags: c, string, char, strtol

I’m working on C code that takes a MAC address as a string, tokenizes it, and stores the individual octets as an array of u_char’s.  I want to store the tokenized MAC address as a struct:

```
typedef struct macAddress{
        u_char addr[6];
}macAddr;
```

Simple enough.  Here’s the conversion function:

```
macAddr* convertMAC( char* str ){

        // Example input:  "52:54:00:6a:20:f1"

        printf( "Now converting :: %s\n", str );
        macAddr* ret = (mac*)malloc( sizeof(mac) );   // calling function will free() later…

        int i = 0;
        char* token = strtok(str, ":");

        while (token != NULL) {
                printf("%d)  ...tokenized :: %s\n", i, token);
                ret->addr[i] = strtol( token, NULL, 16 );
                i++;
                token = strtok(NULL, ":");
        }

        return ret;
}
```

And I whipped up this to check my work:

```
void printMAC( macAddr* mac ){
        printf( "MAC address:" );
        printf( "\t%u:%u:%u:%u:%u:%u\n",
            mac->addr[0], mac->addr[1], mac->addr[2],
            mac->addr[3], mac->addr[4], mac->addr[5] );
}
```

Seems easy enough.  Now, using this driver code…

```
...etc...
     mac* tmpMAC = convertMAC( "52:54:00:6a:20:f1" );
     printMAC( tmpMAC );
...etc...
```

I get this output:

```
Now converting :: 52:54:00:6a:20:f1
0)  ...tokenized :: 52
1)  ...tokenized :: 54
2)  ...tokenized :: 00
3)  ...tokenized :: 6a
4)  ...tokenized :: 20
5)  ...tokenized :: f1
MAC address:    0:82:84:0:106:32
```

Gah!  Not even close.

There are two possibilities here, I think:  First, when I convert the tokenized string into hex (base 16) with this command:

```
ret->addr[i] = strtol( token, NULL, 16 );
```

`strtol()`  is converting accurately, but my `printf("%u", number)` is representing the hex character weirdly on the screen.  Or I don’t understand what `strtol()` is really doing, and the conversion is incorrect.  I suspect the latter, but I can't spot what I'm doing incorrectly in the online documentation.

Anyone see what I’m doing wrong?

Comment: Is this a constrain that you have to use `strtol` or you can `scanf("%x:%x:%x:%x:%x:%x"` ? And, I do not see point in using `strtok` here, I would just take the last character pointer from `strtol`, check if it's `:` and increment and continue. I do not you want `ab::::::de` to be the same as `ab:de`. `printf("%u", number) is representing the hex character weirdly on the screen.` `%u` doesn't print hex.. `Not even close` the numbers are correct, `0x52=82` `0x54=84` `0x6a=106` I only wonder what happened to `f1`

Comment: Probably unrelated to the question, but the `malloc` call looks weird: It uses `sizeof(mac)` and then assigns to a `macAddr *`.

Comment: Are you building with GNU libc?  if so can you use `ether_aton()`?

Comment: FWIW, I happen to get a Segfault on calling `strtok` on a string which happens to be defined as a string immediate: `strtok` will write NUL bytes to the string it has been given, and if that string is in a readonly part of memory, writing that NUL byte gives a segfault.

Comment: @KamilCuk Hi, thanks for writing.  No, there's no requirement to use strtol(), so I'll try scanf()  But I'm relieved to see that you see my numbers are correct!  That's a relief.  thanks!

Comment: @ndim  Hmm...  Interesting, I don't get a segfault in my code.  I'm using GCC on Ubuntu; maybe that's the different.  FWIW, I later switched from strtok() to strtok_r(), based on another post in this forum.  THat works too